# MongoDB or Neo4J for users attending to Event M:M relationship

Tags: mongodb, geolocation, neo4j, many-to-many

Here are my simplified models :

```
User{ String name, Set<UserEvent>, double[] coordinates }

UserEvent{ Event event, Boolean isGoing, Boolean isMaybeGoing }

Event { String name, Set<User> goingUsers, Set<User> maybeGoingUsers, double[] coordinates }
```

I am very confused on how I will implement that and which DB to use.

- I need MongoDB for the geoLocation features 
  `findUsersNearEvent(Event event) / findEventsNearUser(User user)`
- But I think Neo4J is more adapted for the relationship between the User and the Event, there's also the problem of the different type of users : going or maybeGoing. For this I created the UserEvent but I don't know if it's a good design.

If someone has a good design solution or can suggest me what to use for what, it would be nice.

Comment: Your scenario doesn't have nested complicated relationships. I believe mongo is your answer but remember when you ask a question about database scheme and need some design solution advice, you have to be clear about your needs. for example you should mention the possible concurrent clients, size of objects, hardware limitations, and so many other things...

Comment: Well, this is for a personal project, I just want to learn and know which tool to use for which task. 
I may also implement other features like friendship and status also, so I don't know if I have to use both and combine them in a way, or just use neo4j. 
If I store events and friends inside the User Document, it can become really big (even with DataRef).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Neo4j the "UserEvent" would be the relationship between User and Event.

I would probably model it with two relationship-types:

```
(:User)-[:GOING]->(:Event)
(:User)-[:MAYBE_GOING]->(:Event)
```

You can use Neo4j-Spatial to do spatial search in Neo4j, see [Max' blog post](http://maxdemarzi.com/2014/01/31/neo4j-spatial-part-1/) for an intro, he did something similar for restaurants.

a query could look like:

```
START event = node:events("withinDistance(lat,lon,distance)")
MATCH (event)<-[rsvp:GOING|:MAYBE_GOING]-(user)
RETURN event.name, user.name,type(rsvp)
```

#### Update: (:User)-[:FRIEND]->(:User)

You would actually have that between users, you showed it from user to event, which doesn't make sense. 
You are free to project your query results into domain objects however you like.

You can use the two relationship-types :FRIEND and :FRIEND_REQUEST

And then also use that in your queries, e.g. if you also want to invite the friends of a user.

```
START event = node:events("withinDistance(lat,lon,distance)")
MATCH (event)<-[rsvp:GOING]-(user)-[:FRIEND]-(friend)
RETURN event.name, user.name,type(rsvp), collect(friend.name) as friends
```

Or if you want to show a user for an event that he's maybe going to, which of his friends are already going.

```
START event = node:events("withinDistance(lat,lon,distance)")
MATCH (event)<-[rsvp:MAYBE_GOING]-(user)
OPTIONAL MATCH (user)-[:FRIEND]-(friend)-[:GOING]->(event)
RETURN event.name, user.name,type(rsvp), collect(distinct friend.name) as friends_going
```

Comment: I think I need to read more about Neo4J to better understand the possibilities. Thanks for you answer, I can now see a better solution for my needs.

Just to have your confirmation (and some articles if possible), can I do this also with the same logic ? 

 - Friendship between users (but with friend request) ?
   (:User)-[:FRIEND]->(:Event)
   (:User)-[:FRIEND_REQUEST]->(:Event)
 - Collection of Status for each User (Status being an entity with String text and Set<String> tags.

Comment: Oh, and Spring Data Neo4j was the founding project of the Spring Data initiative :)

Answer (score 0):

Michael Hunger already posted an example for Neo4j. For completeness, I will explain how you would solve this with MongoDB.

In MongoDB, you would have a collection `events` and store the attending users in an array in each document.

```
 {
      name:"Event Name",
      location: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ 40, 5 ] },
      attendees: [
           { name: "Alice", status:"maybe" },
           { name: "Bob", status:"sure" },
           { name: "Charlie", status:"sure" }
      ]
 }
```

This schema assumes that usernames are unique and immutable. When they are not, you would use the `_id` of the referenced users in addition to the name. Why in addition and not instead? Because MongoDB doesn't support joins, so you should mirror information in multiple documents to avoid nested queries. Ideally, your most frequent queries should be satisfied by retrieving a single document. When you want a list of attendees of an event, a list of hexadecimal strings is unlikely to be very useful. So any information about the attendees you want to see when looking up an event should be embedded in the event document.

Users would then be in a second collection. You might decide to keep each attended relation twice (once in the event document and once in the user document). Or not. It depends on how frequent your use-cases are: Listing the events of a user or listing the users of an event.

Comment: But how can I store the attendees in the Event in the code (I just know to do it with DBRef or adding a full document). In this case it seems that I have to create a new type of Object with id, name and status, am I right ?

I will try and evaluate it, thank you.

Comment: @skini26 MongoDB objects are typeless. But when you use an object-oriented language with an ODM wrapper for MongoDB, then you will likely need an additional class to represent the redacted user entries in the event document. But that depends on what language you are actually using on the application level.

Comment: I am using Spring Data, so I will create a pojo to represent the attendees. Thanks !